# cannot retrieve data from firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
String branch, semester;



Future<void> _getUserDetails() async {
String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserDatabase').doc(uid).get().then((user) {
  setState(() {
    branch = user.data()['Branch'];
    semester = user.data()['Semester'];
  });
});

print(branch);
print(semester);
```

}

This is the snapshot of my database
[firestore snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmfCB.jpg)

I'm  trying to retrieve data from firestore but I'm getting this error

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

Can someone help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure uid is available as document in firestore

Or you can try below code

```
  Future<void> _getUserDetails() async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserDatabase').doc(uid).get();

    if(doc.exists) { // this will check availability of document
      branch = doc.data()['Branch'];
      semester = doc.data()['Semester'];
    }else{
      branch = "User is not available";
      semester = "User is not available";
    }
    setState((){});
  }
```

---

Register:

```
_firestore.collection('UserDatabase').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).set({
 'Branch': branchVal,
'Email': loggedInUser.email,
'RollNo': rollNoVal,
'Semester': semesterVal,
'Year': yearVal,
});
```

Comment: This block of code gives no error... but on printing "branch and semester" I got null. I tried putting it in setState then also it is null

Comment: Hi, Ive updated my answer please check it

Comment: program flow goes into else block... Any idea how i can prevent that from happening?

Comment: Yes, When you are registering user at thay time use  `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid` as your document id. ex. Firebase.instance.collection("user").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).add({ --});

Comment: I'm getting this error on changing my code in register module   error: The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.

Comment: can you share your register module code in your question? so i can edit it. Thank you

Comment: _firestore.collection('UserDatabase').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).add({
                              'Branch': branchVal,  
                              'Email': loggedInUser.email,  
                              'RollNo': rollNoVal,  
                              'Semester': semesterVal,  
                              'Year': yearVal,  
                            });

Comment: I've updated my answer please use Register code. And let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks man... problem solved... I had spent hours trying to solve this and now it is finally resolved... Thanks again...

Comment: Welcome. If you like my answer then approve it.

Comment: It shows me this error: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserDatabase').doc(uid).get().then((user) {
user.docs.forEach((result) {
  branch = result.data()['Branch'];
semester = result.data()['Semester'];
});
```

});

Comment: error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'.